# finish animation before starting another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem: Whenever I click faster or slower I need last .click() call to finish before the next one starts. If you click the button faster , in the given example, you can see it's leaving divisions with 0 opacity.

What I want to achieve is stacking up till 3-4. I tried some queue code examples, couldn't make it work.

```
$("#addNew").click(function(){
    var _this = $("#scrollable");
    //Switch classes
    _this.find("div.first").switchClass("first","second",500);
    _this.find("div.second").switchClass("second","third",500);
    _this.find("div.third").switchClass("third","fourth",500);
    _this.find("div.fourth").switchClass("fourth","fifth",500);
    // Insert first/new line
    $("<div class='first'>Hello!</div>").css("opacity","0").hide().prependTo(_this).slideDown(function(){$(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},300)})
    $("div.fifth").fadeOut().remove();
});
```

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/gtFyP/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use setInterval

You could combine the below flag solution with setInterval, and thus be able to process clicks occurring during an animation.

Updated your [JS Fiddle again with this alternate solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gtFyP/11/).

```
$(function() {
    var clicking = false;
    var clickCache = 0;

    window.setInterval(function(){
        if (!clicking && clickCache) {
            processClick();
            clickCache--;
        }
    }, 100);

    var processClick = function() {
         var _this = $("#scrollable");

        //Switch classes
        _this.find("div.first").switchClass("first", "second", 500);
        _this.find("div.second").switchClass("second", "third", 500);
        _this.find("div.third").switchClass("third", "fourth", 500);
        _this.find("div.fourth").switchClass("fourth", "fifth", 500);


        clicking = true;
        // Insert first/new line
        $("<div class='first'>Hello!</div>").css("opacity", "0").hide().prependTo(_this).slideDown(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 300, function(){
                clicking = false;
            });
        });
        $("div.fifth").fadeOut().remove();
    };

    $("#addNew").click(function() {
        clickCache++;
    });
});
```

### Use a Flag

You could use a flag - only start an animation if it's false. When you start animating, set it to true, when the animation is done, set it back to false.

I've [modified your JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtFyP/8/).

Comment: This is good, but I was wondering , isn't there a possibility to queue up 3 click's and execute them or something similiar.

But thanks for this one.

Comment: @skmasq I updated my answer to include a solution allowing this

Comment: You know what I really want, if it could move faster.
Basically what I don't you can see in my example, but I want it to go as fast , but not distort like that!